# Find all occurrences where value in one column is the same as another other than NULL values

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported a CSV file including graduate data like grad_year, grad_major, grad_gender, gpa, etc...

The objective is to find all instances in which the originally declared major of the graduate and the major of the graduate upon completion of the program are the same (original_major and grad_major, respectively)

I think I've got it down right, but I'm unsure if I'll be counting null values using the following code, and I would like to eliminate null values from the count if possible

```
import pandas as pd 

grads_df = pd.read_csv('Users/Sas0908/Downloads/grads.csv')

major_same = (grads_df['original_major'] == grads_df['grad_major']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nansum instead of sum (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html)

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

grads_df = pd.read_csv('Users/Sas0908/Downloads/grads.csv')
major_same = np.nansum((grads_df['original_major'] == grads_df['grad_major']))
```